# Terminal program to CSV

Tags: terminal, cmd

I have a little project at work, but I'm stuck in my tracks at the moment. We have quite a few Motorola MC1000 hand held barcode scanners at work, doing nothing at the moment, and I want to get them working again for stock takes and what not.

Now, these were pre-installed with a program called MCA, which is a simple barcode scanner and quantity program, which I'm not sure where it saves this information (maybe in memory), but I am unable to get the data from just connecting the device via USB.

On the program, there is a section called "send data" which then outputs data via COM1 port. I have managed to intercept the old program we used to read the barcodes (there is no way to export from this old program), so I need something new, where I can export barcode, quantity via CSV.

Using serialmon, I have found that I can read the barcode, plus some extra confirmations? then the quantity, plus more confirmations, then the next barcode.

[image: Serial]

[image: Serial 2]

Now I need to know if there is a program out there already that can connect to the com1 port, and then read/respond to the device to download all the barcodes and quantities and then export this to a csv, or even if a simple command prompt bat file could do this?

After some testing earlier, I know the device needs to receive an ack in some way as it times out without this (I could manually do this by sending %0 on a regular basis).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just copy to and from the com port. `copy com1 port.txt`. Note this will only work if communication is terminated by Ctrl + Z from both sides.

Comment: That won't work, as I need to send a signal to the com device after each line.